# Insert/Remove string at specific position in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a text field similar to the below. A line starting with a **"#"** defines a new section. I'm looking for a simple query (not a function) to insert a new line or remove an existing line from a specific position within a *Section*. In the example below, I need to find the position of **#1000** and insert a new line. Likewise, I need to find the position **#1001**, then search until the end of that section *(until #1002)*, and remove a specific line. I know i can use **`select position ('#1000' in "ColumnName") from TableName`**, but I'm not sure what to do next.

```
#1000
NewLine <--- Insert this new line
Line1
Line2
Line3

#1001
Line10 
Line11 <--- Remove this line
Line12

#1002
Line20
Line21
Line22
```

Comment: "Im looking for a simple query (not a function)" If such query even exists - it definitely will not "simple". In general SQL based DBMSes operates with sets, not with sequences. The most advantage of the IT specialist is the ability to choos the most appropriate tool to solve the particular problem. Plain SQL is not relevant for your task.

Answer (score 0):

**For inserting *your_new_line* after *n* lines in the *#kkkk* section the process can be :**

1. you split your text into an array with the `regexp_split_to_array` function
2. you define the position of the #kkkk section in the array with the `array_position` function and you add the *n* offset
3. you insert *your_new_line* in the array at the defined position with the `||` operator
4. you convert the resulting array into a text with the `array_to_string` function

This process is implemented in the following query with your text sample and with *#kkkk* = #1000 and *n* = 0 :

```
SELECT array_to_string(arr[: pos] || array['your_new_line'] || arr[pos+1 :], chr(13))
  FROM regexp_split_to_array(
'#1000
Line1
Line2
Line3

#1001
Line10 
Line11
Line12

#1002
Line20
Line21
Line22', '\n') AS arr
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT array_position(arr, '#1000') + 0 AS pos) AS p
```

and the result is :

```
#1000
your_new_line
Line1
Line2
Line3

#1001
Line10 
Line11
Line12

#1002
Line20
Line21
Line22
```

**For removing the *nth* line in the *#kkkk* section the process can be :**

1. you split your text into an array with the `regexp_split_to_array` function
2. you define the position of the #kkkk section in the array with the `array_position` function and you add the *n* offset
3. you remove from the array the line at the defined position with the `||` operator
4. you convert the resulting array into a text with the `array_to_string` function

This process is implemented in the following query with your text sample and with *#kkkk* = #1001 and *n* = 2 :

```
SELECT array_to_string(arr[: pos-1] || arr[pos+1 :], chr(13))
  FROM regexp_split_to_array(
'#1000
Line1
Line2
Line3

#1001
Line10 
Line11
Line12

#1002
Line20
Line21
Line22', '\n') AS arr
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT array_position(arr, '#1001') + 2 AS pos) AS p
```

and the result is :

```
#1000
Line1
Line2
Line3

#1001
Line10 
Line12

#1002
Line20
Line21
Line22
```

Then you can insert the query in an `UPDATE` command :

```
 UPDATE your_table
    SET (your_column) = (   SELECT array_to_string(arr[: pos-1] || arr[pos+1 :], chr(13))
                              FROM regexp_split_to_array(your_column, '\n') AS arr
                             CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT array_position(arr, '#1001') + 2 AS pos) AS p
                        )
  WHERE condition_to_select_the_row_to_update
```

or you can embed your query in a function and call the function in the `UPDATE` command :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION text_remove(INOUT my_text text, IN section_header text, IN offset_value integer)
RETURNS text LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
$$
    SELECT array_to_string(arr[: pos-1] || arr[pos+1 :], chr(13))
      FROM regexp_split_to_array(my_text, '\n') AS arr
     CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT array_position(arr, section_header) + offset_value AS pos) AS p
$$ ;

 UPDATE your_table
    SET your_column = text_remove(your_column, '#1001', 2)
  WHERE condition_to_select_the_row_to_update ;
```

Comment: Thanks Edouard. Seems like a neat approach. How do i use this to update an existing record containing the above example text? A normal update being something like `Update TableName Set ColumnName Where OtherColumnName`